# Remove single backslashes, convert doubles to single in string

Tags: c#, regex

How best can I convert instances of double backslashes to a single backslash in a string, but remove any occurrences of single backslash?

So this:

```
\|Testing|ABC:1234\\1000-1\|
```

Should convert to this:

```
|Testing|ABC:1234\1000-1|
```

Ideally I want to avoid a temporary replace of '\' to another character.  A solution using .NET or Regular Expressions is preferred.

Comment: Ah thanks Blair, yes mis-print in the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\\(.|$)", "$1");
```

[Edit: Pattern didn't match all possible cases specified in the OP. Thanks for the suggestions, GONeale and Alan M.]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response Princess,

However in a few other scenarios it fails.  I'm using this input:

```
Regex.Replace(@"\L\\A\", @"\\(.)", "$1")
```

It's returning: `L\A\`
When it should return `L\A`.  I understand you are seeking any other character with the ".", but not sure how to fix it as sometimes there will not be other chars.

I managed to put together a working (yet slightly long-winded) approach in C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (text[i] == '\\' && (i + 1 <= text.Length && text[i + 1] == '\\'))
        newText += '\\';
    else if (text[i] == '\\')
        newText += string.Empty;
    else
        newText += text[i];
}
```

But would prefer something more elegant.

Comment: All you need to do is add a check for "end of input" in the capture group:  Regex.Replace(@"\L\\A\", @"\\\(.|$)", "$1")